# Checkin CruiseControl.net config file

Tags: version-control, build-process, cruisecontrol.net

Is there any cruisecontrol.net extension, that monitor the event when the config file modified, and will check-in the config file into the source control?

I found on the cruise-control documentation a method that does the opposite, which is when we modify the config file in the source control, cruise-control will update the file and apply the changes.
But my concern is when someone change the config file from the server, then is there a way to track that?
My thought that by building extension that listen to the event when the config file change, we can push the code to source control, and I am wondering if there is already somebody did that?
Thanks

Comment: Who would change it? Are you leaving your integration server open to everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Christopher Karper. I've seen it work well where the changes to the config file are checked in and then CC.NET pulls the changes down.

If you really need to monitor the area on the continuous integration server where the file is you could use a [File System Source control block](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filesystem+Source+Control+Block) to do that. The simplest way I can think to get the file checked in would be to use an [exec](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task) task to run svn.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You've got that backwards from the way I've seen most implementations.

If you set up a project in your source control, and cruisecontrol.net that is just for the config file, you can update it in the source repos, and have cc.net pull down the updated version each time...

Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher
I am concern that someone else will modify the config file on the cruise-control server without changing the source control.
I will modify my question, to be more clear.